# Binding a select list in javascript, special character escaped

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm binding a select list in javascript. The value it's supposed to have at some index is `"Testing T&Cs"`
The value after rendering is `"Testing T&Cs"`
I'm not sure why `"&Cs"` is being chopped off, it's some ascii thing which is ignored in the string.

```
$("select#selTestList").append($("<option>")
         .val("0")
         .html("-- All Test entries --")
    );
$(results).each(function (index) {
    $("select#selTestList").append($("<option>")
         .val(this.key)
         .html(this.value)
    );
});
```

Comment: html() escapes it, try using .text() instead

Comment: Thank Jaroslav Kadlec, it worked the way u mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `&Cs` with `&amp;Cs`

When you write `"Testing T&Cs"` to HTML, the browser will see the `&` as the start of a special character. You'll have to escape the `&`, that way.

Or, what might be easier, is to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.